# Should a Project Tree plugin like NERDTree be used alongside a fuzzy-searcher plugin like CtrlP?

Tags: vim, nerdtree, ctrlp

Before you light all fuses; I know this might come off as quite opinion-based. I am asking for functional differences, not "is X better than Y and why".

I have been using fuzzysearcher-plugins for some years now, as my previous employer quickly made mockery of me for "needing to actually SEE my files". I've been getting along with CtrlP for a while, but more often than not, when I see a Vim-user whip up his environment, there's NERDTree.

Am I missing out on any important functionality?

Comment: Yes, nerdtree and ctrlp are both essential plugins to vim, if not the most essential ones. Also get nerdtreetabs. Especially when working with big projects and teams, vanilla vim doesn't come close to having enough features to be dangerous.

Comment: I disagree with @AndyRay on the need of NerdTree. CtrlP can be helpful for a large project. However I get along find with ctags, cscope, projectionist, and occasional use of netrw.

Answer (score 3):

Depending the the nature of your project the structure could be very important. It maybe helpful to see you project files. However the use of an always open NerdTree instance is probably not worth it. Please see [Oil and vinegar - split windows and the project drawer](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/).

As for exact functional advantages of having a file explorer always open, I seriously doubt it. I think you would get much more usage out of something like [projectionist](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist) and of course using a fuzzy finder like you are currently doing. Personally I use Tim Pope's [vinegar](https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar) so that if I need a file explorer it is a simple `-` away.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to understand that Vim already comes with a rather powerful file explorer called netrw (`:help netrw`) so there's actually no real *hard* need for another file explorer plugin like NERDTree. But netrw is not really designed to be used as a "side-panel" like those found in other editors and IDEs: "desire" for that feature is what prompted the creation of NERDTree which closely mimics those "side-panels".

Both NERDTree and netrw give you a familiar file navigation interface that's quite handy when you don't have a good knowledge of the project you are working on: they give you a comfortable experience and therefore are quite valuable.

When you know your directory structure well or use alternative means of navigation (I'm thinking about tags), a file explorer — especially one that's "always on" — is not that useful and it's quite legitimate to prefer the simple `:e` and/or `:find` or the higher level abstraction provided by CtrlP, FuzzyFinder, Command-T and friends.

I usually prefer `:e`, `:find`, `:tag` and related commands to using a file explorer but there's always a time when using one is more efficient and, when that time comes, netrw is only an `:Ex` away.

**Both navigation methods are not mutually exclusive *at all.***

A core aspect of the issue worth discussing, IMO, is the *perceived* need for such a "side-panel". Do we *really* need to have a list of the files in our project visible *at all times*? What's the benefit of such a feature when you consider that you never look at it and, really, never use it unless you need to open or interact with some files? Since you have to switch your focus from the editor *to* the file explorer anyway, why not simply, well… "open" the file explorer when you *actually* need it? Of course, the NERDTree window can be toggled but, most of the times, it's just left open. Simply because that's what most people are used to.

Now, comformity, lazyness and ignorance also come into play: NERDTree is listed as a "must have" in every blog post and, AFAIK, it's also provided by default in every crappy distribution so people often install it right away, without even knowing about netrw. The same could be said about CtrlP, of course.